# Scala on Android: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty

Tags: android, exception, scala, dalvik, nosuchmethoderror

I am getting following Exception on Android 2.2.1:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty`

I am calling `text.isEmpty` from Scala. Any idea, how to solve this?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567765/nosuchmethoderror-string-isempty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use JRE/JDK 1.5, which did not have an `isEmpty` method on `String`. This will avoid situations where Scala uses 1.6's `isEmpty` instead of its own. If you have Java libraries as well, be sure to pick ones compatible with 1.5.

Answer (score 10):

`java.lang.String.isEmpty()` was added in Gingerbread (2.3). You will have to write your own replacement function...

Comment: I am compiling against 2.2 and compiler compiles that. It finds `isEmpty` implementation in `IndexedSeqOptimized.isEmpty`.

Comment: That's some Scala weirdism. The Android API in your question definitely didn't appear until Gingerbread. See that http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty() says "Since API Level 9"

Comment: Yes, but I think it should use the implementation from the trait `IndexedSeqOptimized`. The question is, why it is not using this trait?

Answer (score 7):

Alternativly use `(text.length()>0)` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using now `text.length == 0`.

Answer (score 4):

Use TextUtils.isEmpty() instead, available since API level 1.