# NoSuchMethodError: String.isEmpty

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala on Android: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396844/scala-on-android-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-java-lang-string-isempty)

I've just released a new app on Android

I've optimized and obfuscated the code with proguard and tested extensively on my Android 2.3.3 phone. It works all right.

However, I keep getting really strange crash reports in the developer console, such as

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty
```

Isn't `String.isEmpty()` a framework function on all Android devices?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396844/scala-on-android-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-java-lang-string-isempty

Comment: String.isEmpty is new in JDK6.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is `TextUtils.isEmpty("your_String");`, but haven't seen about `your_string.isEmpty()`

I found that `your_string.isEmpty()` works `after 2.2` as it was added in `2.3 GingerBread`. But, before that you can use `TextUtils.isEmpty()`

Comment: [From the Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())

Comment: @LukasKnuth Those are the Oracle docs. The [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) say it was added at API 9 (2.3).