# support multiple OS versions incrementally

Tags: android, version

I'd like to support Android 2.1 devices, but also would like to enable users to move my app to the SD card if they have Android 2.2+

The attribute for that is android:installLocation="auto"

How can I still support 2.1 while enable this attribute for 2.2+?

EDIT: I've set it with build 2.1 and I get a compilation error and I cannot launch my app. The reason I don't want to increase the build target to 2.2 is because if I do that and the app gets installed on 2.1, a bunch of exceptions are thrown and it crashes. I want to make sure that the app works perfectly on 2.1. For an example of what I mean, please see [NoSuchMethodError: String.isEmpty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567765/nosuchmethoderror-string-isempty)

Answer (score 2):

An exact solution for you is in [Android Manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html#Compatiblity).

Comment: Shortly: When your application is installed on a device with an API Level lower than 8, the android:installLocation attribute is ignored and the application is installed on the internal storage.

Comment: I see, but in Eclipse I'm getting compilation error if I set it with 2.1 target, and I cannot launch my app

Comment: @bizso09: As indicated in bullet #3 in the material linked to above, you need to change your build target to API Level 8.

Comment: @CommonsWare please see my edit in the question. I would not like to increase the build target, because unforeseen exceptions may be throwns if the app gets installed on 2.1

Comment: @bizso09: If you are not intending to support Android 2.2, you do not need to `android:installLocation`, as it will not be available. If you are intending to support Android 2.2, you need to fix the "bunch of exceptions are thrown and it crashes", regardless of your build target. A different build target does not cause runtime crashes -- a different build target, at most, causes compile-time issues.

Comment: @CommonsWare please see an example of runtime crash that is caused by different build targets  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567765/nosuchmethoderror-string-isempty

Comment: @bizso09: That question is not "an example of runtime crash that is caused by different build targets". If you want to occasionally remove your `android:installLocation` and run a test compile on a lower build target, be my guest. Or, use MOTODEV's App Validator, as I think it catches this problem. But you have no choice but to follow the documentation for `android:installLocation` and use the proper build target if you wish to use that, whether you happen to like it or not.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, set your minimum API level to 7 and your target API level to 8, more details are in the [Dev Guide](http://file:///C:/workspace/Android/sdk/android-sdk_r10-windows/android-sdk-windows/docs/guide/appendix/install-location.html#Compatiblity).